# create azure aks with basic load blancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

As I understood from the documentation , if you use azure portal to create AKS cluster , you can't use the basic load balancer ,which is free in my current subscription. So how can I then use the basic load balancer with aks.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the CLI to create an AKS with a Basic load balancer.

```
az aks create -g MyRG -n MyCluster --load-balancer-sku basic
```

It's clearly stated in the infobox in the Portal.

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks , but can I use the portal to create the cluster with the standard load balancer and then update it to basic load balancer later on.

Comment: Have you opened the documentation?  Looks like the az aks update command does not let you change the load balancer SKU.

Comment: A compromise is to use the portal to configure all the parts that you can, then at the final step instead of directly creating the cluster from the portal, download the ARM template and edit that to change the load balancer SKU, then submit the template using the CLI.